# Question about the solution of the Burgers' equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

I have the equation $$u_t+uu_x-vu_{xx}=0$$ with $v>0$. The problem is to find the explicit form of the solution if is known that such solution have the form $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$. \ I tried to solve it, but I only could do this $$\left(f-c\right)\frac{df}{dr}-v\frac{d^{2}f}{dr^{2}}=0$$ where $f(r)\equiv f(x-ct)$. But I don´t know how continue.

Comment: It looks to be the viscous burgers’ eqn ie it should be `\nu`$\nu>0$ Is stated in the question body @EricTowers (Its some constant)

Comment: You just need to integrate $$(f-c)f' - v f'' = ff' - cf' - vf'' = 0 \implies \frac{1}{2}f^{2} - cf - vf' = C_{1}$$ then rearrange for $f'$ and integrate again (note that the ODE for $f'$ is a quadratic in $f$, so can be factorised, and is also _separable_).